Reduce curly brace height as to not include over/underbraced text
I have the following expression written in LaTeX:
$$\begin{cases}
        u(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=u(x^0,y^0)+\overbrace{\alpha h_1-\beta h_2}^{\mathclap{\text{$(\alpha,-\beta)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}+g_1(h) \\
        v(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=v(x^0,y^0)+\underbrace{\beta h_1+\alpha h_2}_{\mathclap{\text{$(\beta,\alpha)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}+g_2(h)
  \end{cases}.$$

This outputs a system of two equations using a cases environment whose curly brace spans the space occupied by the two expressions plus that taken up by the text in \underbrace and \overbrace. I'd like to find a way for the brace to only cover the two expressions, thus excluding the text on top and bottom. Thanks in advance to anyone who might help.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Unrelated to your question, but Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

Update: thanks to @egreg's comment, the previous method does not handle the vertical space correctly. So here is another method:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temp
\[\bigg\{
  \begin{aligned}
  u(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=u(x^0,y^0)+\overbrace{\alpha h_1-\beta h_2}^{\mathclap{\text{$(\alpha,-\beta)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}+g_1(h), \\
  v(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=v(x^0,y^0)+\underbrace{\beta h_1+\alpha h_2}_{\mathclap{\text{$(\beta,\alpha)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}+g_2(h).
\end{aligned}\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}



Old answer
Using \smash:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{cases}
        u(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=u(x^0,y^0)+\smash{\overbrace{\alpha h_1-\beta h_2}^{\mathclap{\text{$(\alpha,-\beta)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}}+g_1(h), \\
        v(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=v(x^0,y^0)+\smash{\underbrace{\beta h_1+\alpha h_2}_{\mathclap{\text{$(\beta,\alpha)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}}+g_2(h).
  \end{cases}\]

\end{document}


Notes:

Using $$...$$ for display equation is not recommended any more.
Please always provide a complete code example when asking questions.


The vertical spacing will be wrong, I'm afraid.

You're right@egreg Let me think how to improve.

You can use \smash, but this would have very bad effects on the vertical spacing.
Here's my proposal, where the cases environment is typeset twice, once with smashed parts and one as a vertical phantom with normal underbrace and overbrace, so the spacing turns out to be correct.
I also present an example equivalent to Stephen's in order to see what goes wrong.
Don't forget \hspace{-1em} when you use cases without side conditions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{\donthide{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
\newcommand{\obrace}[2]{\donthide{\overbrace{#1}^{#2}}}
\newcommand{\donthide}[1]{{#1}} % normal behavior

\newcommand{\ubracezero}[2]{\ubrace{#1}{\mathclap{#2}}}
\newcommand{\obracezero}[2]{\obrace{#1}{\mathclap{#2}}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{commentedcases}{b}{%
  \begingroup\let\donthide\smash
  \begin{cases} #1 \end{cases}
  \endgroup
  \vphantom{\begin{cases} #1 \end{cases}}
}{}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
\begin{commentedcases}
  u(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=u(x^0,y^0)
    +\obracezero{\alpha h_1-\beta h_2}{(\alpha,-\beta)\cdot(h_1,h_2)}
    +g_1(h), \\
  v(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=v(x^0,y^0)
    +\ubracezero{(\beta h_1+\alpha h_2}{(\beta,\alpha)\cdot(h_1,h_2)}
    +g_2(h).
\end{commentedcases}
\hspace{-1em}
\]
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
\begin{cases}
  u(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=u(x^0,y^0)
    +\smash{\obracezero{\alpha h_1-\beta h_2}{(\alpha,-\beta)\cdot(h_1,h_2)}}
    +g_1(h), \\
  v(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=v(x^0,y^0)
    +\smash{\ubracezero{\beta h_1+\alpha h_2}{\beta,\alpha)\cdot(h_1,h_2)}}
    +g_2(h).
\end{cases}
\]
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}

Generally speaking, my suggested \obrace and \ubrace commands are better than the legacy \overbrace and \underbrace with respect to spacing.
I also provide \obracezero and \ubracezero that hide the width of the superscript or subscript respectively.


Since you're not using much of the cases machinery at all, I would like to suggest you take a different approach:

use a \left\{ \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \right. approach

use \smash[t]{\overbrace{...}^{...}} in the first row and \smash[b]{\underbrace{...}_{...} directives in the second row

to preserve the overall height of the entire construct, which amounts to about 6 \textstyle rows, just place
\begin{array}{c} \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \end{array} % 6 empty rows

to the immediate right of the construct. (Using 5 empty rows would work too.)



\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for filler text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\[
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
&u(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=u(x^0,y^0)
+\smash[t]{\overbrace{\alpha h_1-\beta h_2}^{\mathclap{\text{$(\alpha,-\beta)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}}
+g_1(h) \\
&v(x^0+h_1,y^0+h_2)=v(x^0,y^0)
+\smash[b]{\underbrace{\beta h_1+\alpha h_2}_{\mathclap{\text{$(\beta,\alpha)\cdot(h_1,h_2)$}}}}
+g_2(h)
\end{aligned}
\right. 
\begin{array}{c} \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \end{array} % an 'array' with 6 empty rows
\]
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{document}

